# Can not run website in mvc project on Rider (JetBrains)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jetbrains-ide, rider

Does anyone use Rider from JetBrains? I'm creating an ASP.net MVC project like on Pic 1. When I open in browser, it can't run (Pic 2).

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

I think there might be a port conflict, so I tried changing the port, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me please, thank you so much.

Comment: Old ASP.NET 4.x is only fully supported on Windows, so any attempt to run it elsewhere can end up like this. Not a surprise when Rider tries to use port 5000 but that's for ASP.NET Core.